# How To Do Sum Of (BS,HRA,CONV,BA,WASH,MEDICAL ) These all Rows Except EmployeeId

Tags: sql

[image]

How To Do Sum Of These RowColumns i.e bs,hra,conv,ba,wash,medical... 
I generated this Using Pivot and now want to sum of it

Comment: Hello @Inc, What is your database ? Also please add some example data (text not image) what you expect to get at the end ?

Comment: Simply sum them (`+`) wrapping into `COALESCE`.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can do sum :

```
select employeeid, sum(coalesce(bs, 0) + coalesce(hra, 0) + 
                       coalesce(ba, 0) + coalesce(wash, 0) + coalesce(medical, 0)
                      ) as Total 
form ( <subquery here>  ) t
group by employeeid;
```